# magento 2.3 add store view switcher in custom header template

Tags: store-view, magento2.3.1, header, language-switcher

I have two store views for two languages english and spanish in magento 2.3 EE. 
The english store is default one and I want to add store view switcher drop down in my custom header template.

How to show that ?

The main requirement is that I want only one page in spanish with complete spanish header, footer and content. So, for that I have created the above two store views.
I am using custom weltpixel theme.
But store switcher is not showing up on header.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you use magento default theme then in `layout/default.xml` add below code before `</body>` tag

```
<move element="header.switchers" destination="header.panel" before="header.links" />
```

UPDATED: 
 full path should be like this - **app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendorname/Theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
**

Put below code in default.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

run **php bin/magento cache:clean** command
run **php bin/magento cache:flush** command

Now store switcher will show on the header part.

Comment: @chanchal : please check above solution, if it worked, please accept answer.

Comment: I tried the above solution,but it's not working. I have custom header template file.

Comment: you need to add in xml layout file not in template file.

Comment: yes I have added in xml like below- 

        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="bd_custom_header" as="bd_custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/bd_custom-header.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

But still not working.

Comment: add before="header.links"

Comment: Added before="header.links" but still not showing.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Comment: I have added code <move element="store_switcher" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.links" />  in my custom theme's default.xml but still not showing. Cleaned and flushed cache also.

Comment: ohh dear you use one language only, 
Language switcher shows for multiple languages per website. It does not show if each website has only one language. create one more store view for enaglish en then add in default.xml file
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>

Comment: if <block> is already there then try <move> before </body> tag.
<move element="header.switchers" destination="header-wrapper" before="-"/>

Comment: Please check the above screenshot and updated question. I have already created another store view for spanish.

Comment: you need to rename "Dafault" to language code like en name english
better create one more store name as english and code is en then add "<move element="header.switchers" destination="header-wrapper" before="-"/>" before </body> close tag in default.xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99422/discussion-between-chanchal-and-sangeeta).

Comment: This isn't working for me either just moved theme onto 2.3.4 and it doesn't seem to be taking any effect does anyone know if it's a bug?